# sonarqube eclipse plugin Usage

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

I Just figured out, there should be a project in sonar server before you can integrate sonarqube with your project in eclipse, I don't see much benefit as I already ran the sonarrunner to have that project on the sonar server and I have the analysis for that one on sonar application i.e. http://localhost:9000 (in my case). Is it just for the sake of having it in eclipse we install the plugin and see the results or am I missing some point or else Is there any way we can run analysis within eclipse without having the project on sonar server at the first place. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, there are a couple things going on in it. I'll take them one by one:

> Is it just for the sake of having it in eclipse we install the plugin and see the results

The point of installing the Eclipse SonarQube plugin is to be able to do a [pre-commit analysis](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Pre-commit+Check) & make sure you aren't committing new technical debt

> there should be a project in sonar server before you can integrate sonarqube with your project in eclipse

Yes. Since the point is to find *new* issues, there must be a baseline & that's established by your full SonarQube analysis (when you ran sonar-runner).

> Is there any way we can run analysis within eclipse without having the project on sonar server at the first place.

That's actually on the "Coming Soon" list. This is already available in Visual Studio 2015 & the same model is in the works for Eclipse & IDEA.